# Ruby on Railsでテーブル同士を比較したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

railsのテーブル同士の指定したカラムが重複していた場合、重複しているレコードが無い新たなテーブル、もしくは配列を作りたいです。
例えば名前の重複を見る場合は、以下のような２つのテーブルを
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下のようにしたいと考えています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コードのイメージがつかないため、どなたかご教授していただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 配列に変換して結合だと、毎回全データをダウンロードしてくることになるので大変効率が悪く、せっかくのDBを使う意味が薄れてきてしまいます。ユーザーが増えた時にサーバーが耐えられない可能性が大きいです。

特にそういうった問題がない場合はいいですが、そうじゃない場合はユニークなユーザーテーブルなどを別途用意した方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

あまりうまい方法はないと思います。

```rb
Model1.all.to_a + Model2.where.not(name: Model1.all.select(:name)).to_a
```

とやるぐらいじゃないかな、となんとなく思っています。

Comment: なるほど、一度配列にするしかないようですね。ご教授いただきありがとうございました。